# How do I move the cursor to the center of current line?

Tags: cursor-movement

Is there a way I can move my cursor to the middle of the current line? By middle, I don't mean the middle of the screen, but the middle of the line of text, regardless of length.

The shortcut <kbd>M</kbd> moves the cursor to the middle of the screen - is there an equivalent shortcut to move the cursor to the middle of the line?

Comment: So is middle middle of the full line or middle of the screen width?

Comment: @muru Was thinking of middle of full line

Comment: Could you add that to the question as well? And what do you expect to happen with wrapping?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know of any builtin ways to do this. However, you can easily make a map to do it:

```
nnoremap µ :exe 'normal! '.(virtcol('$')/2).'\|'<cr>
```

Ingo Karkat proposed the following variant [in the comments](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/how-do-i-move-the-cursor-to-the-center-of-current-line#comment4560_2463) that also works in visual mode.

```
noremap <expr> gM (virtcol('$') / 2) . '<Bar>'
```

Unfortunately, it's also triggered in select mode. As a consequence, I prefer using two mappings, one for each mode:

```
nnoremap <expr> gM (virtcol('$') / 2) . '<Bar>'
xnoremap <expr> gM (virtcol('$') / 2) . '<Bar>'
```

Comment: This variant will also work correctly for visual mode: `noremap <expr> gM (virtcol('$') / 2) . '<Bar>'`

Answer (score 23):

The built-in [`gm`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#gm) does exactly this.

Comment: Note that this takes you to the middle of the line with respect to the *console width*, not with respect to the *line length*.  So, if you have a line of 10 characters and a console that is 80 characters wide, the cursor will end up on the 10th character in the line (because it's "trying" to get to the 40th), not the 5th.

Comment: Yep. From the question, it is not clear whether we're looking for the middle of the line or the middle of the screen. Based on the analogy to `M`, I assumed screen.

Comment: Actually I just tried this on a wide (about 180 chars) screen with 80-char text. The cursor went to the *end* of the line. Doesn't seem a very useful command.

Comment: @Ben Did it go to the end of the line, or did it go as close to the center of the screen width as it could get? Try it with a line that's more than 50% as wide as the screen, or try it with `:set virtualedit=all`.

Comment: Yes but the OP was asking for a command to jump to the middle of the line text, not the middle of the screen. So it doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 8):

As of [October 2019](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/8b530c1ff91f07cf6b0289a536992b7dfbc86598), we have [`gM`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#gM), which moves the cursor to the middle of the line. This requires Vim 8.1.2231 or later.

Answer (score 4):

To add to Luc's answer, there's also the [Easymotion](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-easymotion) plugin, which makes moving quickly to a specific position a breeze. Pressing `<Leader><Leader>w` will highlight which key you can press to move to a specific word. That way you could easily move to a word in the middle of the current line.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go to the middle of the text (not taking into account the whitespace in the beginning of the line), this will work:

```
function! s:Gm()
  execute 'normal! ^'
  let first_col = virtcol('.')
  execute 'normal! g_'
  let last_col  = virtcol('.')
  execute 'normal! ' . (first_col + last_col) / 2 . '|'
endfunction
nnoremap <silent> gm :call <SID>Gm()<CR>
```

I don't think this will work in visual mode, however.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install vim 8.2

To move your cursor to the middle of a line, enter
`gM`

(gM is not in vim 8.1)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: I think the majority of your answer is covered by this one: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22397/10604

Comment: "gM is not in vim 8.1" - technically wrong. It was added in 8.1.2231, which is still 8.1, but a fairly late version of 8.1. (8.1.2424 was the last patch 8.1 received)

Comment: @D.BenKnoble
@Zoe
You are right. There were two different versions of Vim on my two different machines - 8.1 on one, 8.2 on the other. Sorry I did not notice the detailed version numbers. I tried it on both machines. `gM` worked on my 8.2 machine, but  did not work on my 8.1. I upgraded 8.1 to 8.2, then `gM` worked.